Compare emails to check if they are equal gives error
I would like help with this question. If email1 and email2 (Strings) are equal when submit is pressed, an alert message box will be displayed. I didn't add an else statement.
Error:

Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: email1 is not defined
at  (\script.js:7:17)



function equals_function(email1, email2) {
  if (email1 != email2) {
    alert("You didn't enter matching email addresses in the input!") // output alter
  }
}

equals_function(email1, email2)
<form>
  <label for="email1">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="emailone" id="emailone">

  <p>
    <label for="email2">Email Address Confirmation:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailtwo" id="emailtwo">
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>




Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. While it is not required to speak perfect English, at least some kind of grammar and spelling is mandatory. I have no idea what you're asking from us or what problem you face.

Your JavaScript function looks correct. What error are you getting in the vs code?

"was getting an error" - Please [edit] your question and add in the full error (as text) inside it - Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

You are not passing anything to the function that the script recognises.
You need to use something like this - note I made both field required so I do not have to test if they are empty


window.addEventListener('load', (e) => { // when elements are available
  document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const form = e.target,
      email1 = form.emailone.value.trim(),
      email2 = form.emailtwo.value.trim();
    if (email1 !== email2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Please enter the same email');
    }
  });
});
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="email1">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="emailone" id="emailone" required>

  <p>
    <label for="email2">Email Address Confirmation:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailtwo" id="emailtwo" required>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>



